# KSQL - loop through of JSON array

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a kafka topic data with the following structure:

```
    { property1:value1, 
      property2:value2, 
      property3: [    
       {
        subprop1:subval11,
        subprop2:subval12,
        subprop3:subval13    
       },    
       {
         subprop1:subval21,
         subprop2:subval22,
         subprop3:subval23
        },
        ...
     ] 
   }
```

in the KSQL documentation, I can declare a stream or table with the ARRAY format for the column, however, when I create the stream, I need to loop through this array.

My KSQL output should be:

```
PropertyID1 |subprop1 | subprop2 | subprop3
Value1      |subval11 | subval12 | subval13
Value1      |subval21 | subval22 | subval23
```

so what should my create stream function look like?

So far I have:

```
CREATE STREAM testarrayjsonstream \
  (property1 VARCHAR, \
   property3 ARRAY) \
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic1', \
        VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

then I can do:

```
Create Stream testarrayjsontopic as \
select property1,property3[0]->subprop1 from testarrayjsonstream
```

but that only gives me only the first array element - I need to loop through to get all array elements. any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

KSQL doesn't currently support this. You can upvote/comment on the issue [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/527).

Comment: I have done a +1 for the issue. any workarounds for this issue until we get a resolution from KSQL?

Comment: Use Kafka Streams